# How to add disabled select property on select based on the json I got from the ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, selectize.js

I have a materialize select box like

```
<select id="create-event-session-name" name="session_name" class="validate">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Session</option>
    <option value="measurements">Measurements</option>
    <option value="bath">Bath</option>
    <option value="post_partum">Post Partum</option>
    <option value="nicu">NICU</option>
    <option value="mics">Mics.</option>
</select>
```

I have a data from ajax call in which I have session names. I want to add **disabled selected** attribute to the option if that value exists in the `JSON` that I have

```
$('#create-event-user').on('change', function() {
  var userId = $('#create-event-user').val();
  var sessionStr = '<option value=""    disabled selected>Select User</option>';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/get-user-sessions/" + userId,
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        console.info(item.session_name);
        var mapped = $("select#create-event-session-name option").map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        console.info(mapped);
        //console.info($('#create-event-session-name option[value = "''"]'));
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: There will be only one value which will be same ?

Comment: nops, there can be many, like form ajax I can get measurements, bath, post_partum.... I want to disable all these three options

Comment: Try this at end of after 'console.log(mapped)` . `$("#create-event-user option[value='"+item.session_name+"']").attr("disabled",true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the options having the same value and if such a option exists set its slelected and disabled attribute:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/get-user-sessions/" + userId,
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var opt = $('#create-event-session-name option[value="'+item.session_name+'"]');
        if(opt.length) {opt.attr('selected',true).attr('disabled',true);}
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if dropdown contains value add `disabled` attribute

```
$("#create-event-user option[value='"+item.session_name+"']").attr({"disabled":true,"selected":"selected"});
```

Complete Code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/get-user-sessions/" + userId,
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        console.info(item.session_name);
        var mapped = $("select#create-event-session-name option").map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        console.info(mapped);
        $("#create-event-user option[value='"+item.session_name+"']").attr({"disabled":true,"selected":"selected"});
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
  });
```